# Rounding down divided numbers with php

Tags: php, row, while-loop, echo, number-formatting

Below is the code I am using within a while loop to display a number within a table row and it's amount divided by 200 right next to it (**'amount'**).

It works ok in that it takes off the decimals and divides by 200 but I was wondering how do I round it down?

For example If I have 850 it will echo '4', however if the amount is over 900 it will echo '5'. I gather that if it is over the halfway mark of 200 it will round up, but how can I round down everything that is below 200?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="left"><strong>' . $row['name'] . '</strong></td> ';
    echo  '<td align="left">' . $row['amount'] . '</td>';
    echo  '<td align="center"><strong><font color="#be0f34">'; 
    echo number_format("{$row['amount']}"/200,0); 
    echo '</font></strong></td>';
    echo  '<td align="center">' . $row['date'] . '</td>
    </tr>
    ';
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Do you anticipate having to deal with negative numbers at some point? If so, do you want them to go to the next lowest number (does -1.5 go to -2) or mirror positive numbers (-1.5 goes to -1)?

Comment: @Mark E: It would not make sense to have a negative *amount* ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: unfamiliar with accounting, eh?

Comment: @Mark E, I won't be using negative numbers at this point

Answer (score 3):

Use `floor()`:

```
echo number_format(floor($row['amount']/200),0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`floor()` is what you want.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `floor()` instead of `number_format()`

```
echo floor($row['amount']/200);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be forcing a type-conversion to a string in the first argument you're passing to `number_format`. Also, the second argument defaults to zero, so you don't need to specify that explicitly. You can just use `number_format($row['amount'] / 200);` on that line.

As far as your question is concerned, I'm gathering that you want to round when the amount is above 200 only so that you do not get "1" as a result when the amount is >= 100. To do that, you will need to do something along the lines of this:

```
$divided_amount = $row['amount'] / 200;
$divided_amount = floor($divided_amount) ? number_format($divided_amount) : '0';

// display code here
```

That will only `number_format` (and thus, round) if the divided amount is >= 200. Otherwise it'll floor (which we know will return zero since we just tested it).